# Update UI in Android

Tags: android

There are many activities in my application and one subclass of Application (ApplicationEx class). My application send and receive SIP messages. If new message is received then there is a callback of message received in ApplicationEx class. From ApplicationEx class how to inform UI (specific activity) ? And for every message it is not efficient to broadcast intent as per this link. Which methods available to update UI ? and which method suits for this application ?

Comment: Update the UI in what way?  To force a redraw call `invalidate()` on the root `View` of the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used handler to update UI. To update UI I override handleMessage method of Handler.Callback.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed registering a listener (ie. create an `OnDirtyViewListener`) and have your `Activity` register to it. Then when the `Application` deems the `View` is dirty, fire off the call and have the `Acitvity` `postInvalidate()` its top level `View`.

Comment: can you explain your answer in detail?

Comment: Create an `OnDirtyViewListener` interface with the method `onViewDirty(Object... args)` in your `Application`. In an `Activity`s `onCreate(Bundle)` method have the `Activity` register call a `registerOnDirtyViewListener(OnDirtyViewListener)` method in the `Application`. Then when ever the `Application` wants to refresh the `View`, it will just call the `onViewDirty()` method of the listener. This will force the `Activity` to do what ever you set up the method to do (mainly `invalidating()` the dirty `View`).